# SQL query instead of loop

Tags: sql

I have data corpus like:

```
DeviceID     Country
id_1         country_1
id_2         country_1
id_3         country_1
id_4         country_2
id_5         country_2
id_6         country_2
```

and I want result like:

```
DistCountries    DeviceCount
country_1        3
country_2        3
```

I have used following query to extract distinct country list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Country) as DistCountries FROM devices;
```

But, I don't know what can be done to get the required results. Can this be done instead of loops? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT country, count(*) 
FROM devices
GROUP BY country;
```